# Correct solution for dynamics problem (F=ma)?

Tags: solution-verification, physics, classical-mechanics

Any help appreciated with this problem.

*A train consists of a railway engine of mass $M$ tonne coupled to two trucks, each of mass $m$ tonne. Initially the train is at rest and each coupling is slack to the extent of $a$ meters.  A constant force $P$ tonne wt is then applied to the engine to drive the train forwards.  Neglecting frictional resistance, find the time that elapses before the second truck starts to move.  $\bigg[Ans : \sqrt{\dfrac{2a(2M + m)}{Pg}} \bigg]$.*

My attempt.

Using Newton's 2nd Law of motion ($F = ma$) and $s = ut + \frac{1}{2} at^2$ I found the time when the first couple becomes taut.   $t_1 = \sqrt{\dfrac{2aM}{Pg}}$.

Using the the same logic I found the time taken for the second couple to become taut.  In this case the mass is $(M + m)$.  This gives  $t_2 = \sqrt{\dfrac{2a(M +m)}{Pg}}$.

So I just added $t_1 + t_2 = \sqrt{\dfrac{2aM}{Pg}} + \sqrt{\dfrac{2a(M +m)}{Pg}}$.

Which obviously isn't the answer given.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something is not clear to me. What happens at $t_1$? Does the velocity of the car suddenly becomes equal to the velocity of the engine? If yes, then you have $u\ne 0$ when you start calculating $t_2$

Comment: My understating of the question is the velocity of the 1st car starts moving from rest..

Comment: Then the acceleration of the 1st car depends on the tension in the coupling. And the engine will still move faster than the 1st car, so the coupling length will not be constant

Comment: Thanks.  I think we need to assume the coupling is $a$.  This was taken from a Year 12 Applied Mathematics book from the 1970s so I don't think we need to go down the coupling length not being constant scenario.

Comment: Right, but that means that at $t_1$ the 1st car will move with the same velocity as the engine

Comment: That makes the problem very tricky...

Comment: If you treat the instant where the first coupling is taut as a momentum conserving collision, then you arrive at the required answer

Comment: Thanks for your comment Sal... Could you expend on that process?  How does that involve $t$, using conservation of momentum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll call the constant force $F$. The time until the first coupling is taut is; as you say

$$
t_1=\sqrt{\frac{2aM}{F}}
$$

The velocity of the engine at $t_1$ is $v_1=\frac{F}{M}t_1$.

At $t=t_1$, suppose the engine and first truck have a momentum conserving collision, and they move at the same velocity $V$ just after the collision. Then

$$
p_\text{initial}=Mv_1:=p_\text{final}=(M+m)V\\
\therefore V=\frac{M}{M+m}v_1=\frac{\sqrt{2aMF}}{M+m}
$$

After the collision, we have a new initial value problem $F=(M+m)\ddot{x}$. I'll define a new $t=0$, $x=0$ here, so the initial conditions are $x(0)=0$, $\dot{x}(0)=V$. The solution is

$$
x(t)=Vt+\frac{Ft^2}{2(M+m)}
$$

The second truck will move when $x(t_2)=a$. Solving the quadratic equation for $t_2$ (picking the positive root, and simplifying) yields

$$
t_2=-\sqrt{\frac{2aM}{F}}+\sqrt{\frac{2a(2M+m)}{F}}
$$

The total time is $t_1+t_2=\sqrt{\frac{2a(2M+m)}{F}}$

Comment: Thank-you SO much Sal.  I really appreciate the amount of effort in your solution.  I owe you a coffee!  Thanks again

Comment: @Stephan No problem, glad it helped!

Comment: Thanks again Sal.  I went down the quadratic equation hole to find $t$ originally , but made a simple error.  When I tried again I got your answer.   But you guidance certainly confirmed by methodology.